# custom UISwitch won't change state

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiswitch

I have a custom uiswitch class, nothing special, the header looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Course;
@class Student;

@interface AttandanceSwitch : UISwitch

@property (strong,nonatomic) Course *course;
@property (strong,nonatomic) Student *student;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UISwitch *originalSwitch;

-(id)initWithSwitch:(UISwitch *)newSwitch Student:(Student *)student andCourse:(Course *)course;
-(NSString *) description;

@end
```

the .m file looks as follows:

```
#import "AttandanceSwitch.h"
#import "Course.h"
#import "Student.h"

@implementation AttandanceSwitch 

@synthesize course,student,originalSwitch;

-(id)initWithSwitch:(UISwitch *)newSwitch Student:(Student *)studentP andCourse:(Course *)courseP
{

    self = [super init];
    self.course = courseP;
    self.student = studentP;
    self.originalSwitch = newSwitch;

    [self.originalSwitch setOn:YES];

    return self;
}

-(NSString *) description 
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Student: %@, Course: %@, Switch: %@",student.name,course.name,[originalSwitch description]];
}

@end
```

So whats actually the problem - when I create a new object of this class using initWithSwitch, I cant set the originalSwitch value. I even tried to set it statically (see     self.originalSwitch setOn:YES above), but even if I do that, the switch is still off.

Any ideas on how to get this working would be very appreciated...

this is a excerpt from usage of this class in tableviewcell:

```
UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; 
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
AttandanceSwitch *customSwitch = [[AttandanceSwitch alloc] initWithSwitch:switchView Student:student andCourse:courseToTrack];
```

Student and Course get filled allright.

Comment: You probably want to provide the code where you add the switch and call it also. You subclass UISwitch and set a switch as an instance var - why? UISwitch is probably a part of your View, no? So I'm wondering if a 'Student' and a 'Course' are placed well in this class.

Comment: I got a little confused - this is a excerpt from usage of this class in tableviewcell:

`UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    AttandanceSwitch *customSwitch = [[AttandanceSwitch alloc] initWithSwitch:switchView Student:student andCourse:courseToTrack];`

Student and Course get filled allright. 

Cld you restate your question pls?

Comment: Check the code where you add the switch to a View. Is it the 'original' switch that you add as a subview?

Comment: nope - as you can see from the code in the comment above, I create a UISwitch and then pass it to my custom switch initwithswitch method. 

then, when it gets created, I get to the original switch by using customswitch.originalswitch.

Comment: And do you then write something like [self.view addSubView:customswitch.originalswitch]  ?  I've just done it myself the exact same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work if you call it like this in your ViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
UISwitch *newSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
AttandanceSwitch *customSwitch = [[AttandanceSwitch alloc] initWithSwitch:newSwitch];
[self.view addSubView:customSwitch.original];
[customSwitch.original setOn:YES];
```